# Can't Have Separate Billing & Shipping Addresses

Tags: checkout, shipping, shipping-address, billing-address, field

I am having quite a big issue and its starting to get ridiculous, I have had complaints from customers saying that they can't have separate billing and shipping addresses.

I have since tried to put through a test order and when you uncheck My billing and shipping address are the same tick box, enter the shipping address, hit update and then continue the order, all that happens is that I get an error message saying:

> Please check the shipping address information. the street is a
>   required field. the city is a required field. the telephone is a
>   required field.

Which to me makes absolutely no sense!

I am starting to give up on Magento because stuff like this is easily configurable in other CMS's

Comment: Are you deleted the street and city fields

Comment: Nope they are in there.

Comment: check the console for errors this could cause issues with form showing